# Design Lib CONTAINS support-v7 Why to compile both

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

### I got Shoked when I obbserved this

every single peace of code of a gradle modle that I see on random websites, popular websites, stackoverflow question and answers, coders compile desing library along with appcompact-v7 and even more with recyclerview and cardview and suppport lib, while the design lib contains all of them and I do use all that and import them very normally without a single problem. this make me very confused please some of experts explain, with all do thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while the design lib contains all of them

The `com.android.support:design` artifact does not "contain" "appcompact-v7 and even more with recyclerview and cardview and suppport lib", at least for the standard English definition of "contain". If you look inside the AAR for, say, `com.android.support:design:23.4.0`, you will not find any classes from those other artifacts.

`com.android.support:design` *does* have [transitive dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency) on other artifacts. Specifically, when you depend upon `com.android.support:design:23.4.0`, you will also depend upon:

- `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0`
- `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0`
- `com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0`

Those, in turn, will also pull in:

- `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0`
- `com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0`
- `com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0`

`com.android.support:design` relies upon classes and resources from `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` and kin, which is why it has these dependencies. If you depend upon `com.android.support:design`, you indirectly depend upon all those other artifacts. Gradle will pull them in automatically.

Note that `com.android.support:design`, nor any of its dependencies, seem to depend upon `com.android.support:cardview`. Admittedly, I only checked `23.4.0`.

Comment: right I checked Android Doc before and they said it contain support-v4 and nothing else like what you say. but how could you explain that i can import all those "recyclerview, appcompact.." v7 without problems if they are not in my gradle nor in design lib, i didnt see an answer except that gradle automaticlly compile them ok then why we but there compiling code lines? Im sorry if that soumds selly but im not an expert and would like to know

Comment: @codeketty: "right I checked Android Doc before and they said it contain support-v4 and nothing else like what you say" -- if you like, give me a link to where it says this, and I will work to get the documentation corrected.

Comment: @codeketty: In addition to the answer, you might wish to read the Wikipedia page that I linked to in the answer. You might also wish to read [the Gradle documentation on dependency management basics](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html). When you depend upon `com.android.support:design:23.4.0`, you automatically pull in the other six libraries denoted by bullets in my answer. This is handled for you by Gradle and the way those libraries were built.

Comment: here you are " http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html?m=1" look at the end after the compile code line. and sorry it says support-v4 and appcompact, and will be included not contained in the lib. but still the same confuse for my about that recyclerview-v7 can be imported without its compile code and all still compile them including appcompact

Comment: yes I dont have a problem with that fact I just know it and its nice to know but then its waste of time to add their dependency and if I didnt do that im not missing any feauters right?

Comment: @codeketty: The blog post you cited is a year old and refers to version `22.2.0`. *That* version does not depend upon `recyclerview-v7`. The current one (`23.4.0`) does. Libraries change. "then its waste of time to add their dependency" -- I would say that it is not necessary for you declare a dependency on `recyclerview-v7` yourself, though you could as a form of documentation. "if I didnt do that im not missing any feauters right?" -- correct.

Comment: aha now i feel safe, right i tested this only on 23.0.1 and 23.2.1, i think that should be mentioned cause alot of people do that and i think it will cause errors of duplicated resources when using multidex or somthing i forget what it call. right?"just in case I saw a question about problem like, that i remember i did :D"